# Cannot FInd a Driver for a Wireless PCI Card, Netis Systems WF-2117

Tags: wireless, drivers, ralink

I'm running 12.04 and do not have a clue how to set up my wireless card. The strange thing is the box says that it's made by netis.  But on a query (`lspci`) of the device, it says:

`01:02.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. Device 5362`

I guess Ralink manufactured their chips. I looked on the NETIS site, and they only have a windows driver. I looked on the Ralink site, which has moved, and they do not have a driver for that device or model number.

Could someone suggest a driver that might work as far as the ralink ones go or is there a workaround maybe?

Hoping someone else has some time and can walk a newb through this task.

Comment: Well, I did some looking into the disk that came with it, it appears that the driver is the same as the Ralink 2860.  I'm hoping to install from the Ralink linux driver site, but do not know how to do so with a .bin file.

Comment: post output of `lspci -knn | grep -EiA3 net`

Comment: matthew@mormegrille:/$ lspci -knn | grep -EiA3 net
01:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:5362]
 Subsystem: Ralink corp. Device [1814:5362]
 Kernel modules: rt2800pci

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP no longer looking for answers, He/She returned the card.

Answer (score 0):

rt2800pci is a project produced by the rt2x00 driver that supports the PCI chipset Ralink 802.11n. you can see the list of supported devices by typing:

```
modinfo rtl2800pci
```

this is the output (apart the kernel version):

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800pci.ko
license:        GPL
firmware:       rt2860.bin
description:    Ralink RT2800 PCI & PCMCIA Wireless LAN driver.
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     259E8826760AAB9E718FD85
alias:          pci:v00001814d0000539Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001814d0000539Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
...
alias:          pci:v00001814d00005362sv*sd*bc*sc*i*<-- your chipset
alias:          pci:v00001814d00005360sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
...
depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2800lib,rt2x00mmio,rt2x00pci,eeprom_93cx6
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.11.0-19-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)
```

Mount the drivers in the kernel

```
sudo modprobe rt2800pci
```

type `dmesg` for print kernel message on your screen.

[Here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/rt2800pci) you can find the project page

If it does not work you can try the manufacturer's drivers. [Here](http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads/) is driver page.

Another possibility is to use [ndiswrapper](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Main_Page), but i'm not sure it is work. There are many guides on the internet that you can find easily. This one is [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=885847)

I hope this helps

Comment: matthew@mormegrille:~$ sudo modprobe rt2800pci
[sudo] password for matthew: 
matthew@mormegrille:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.    No real response from the modprobe.

Comment: Even though your answer may work, it has very little details in it. Please add more details like what the command does and what the problem in OP's system is.

Comment: I've tried a few things, the card is still not working.  What normally happens when a wireless card gets plugged into Ubuntu?  Does it show up in the network interface same as a wired connection?  Because the system obviously "sees" it as an active pci card, and I've tried a few different things for drivers, but still no wireless connections and it's not showing up anywhere other than a query of pci hardware connected...  I appreciate the help, regardless of details in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question.  Nothing would get that card to work.  I am returning it today and in the meantime using a USB network card from Level1 that worked immediately after installing with WINE.  Thank you all for trying to help.